# How to redirect to a page in bootstrap and angularjs when URL is accessed on IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very basic requirement.

I want my website written in bootstrap and angularjs to show a different page {landing page} when accessed through internet explorer.

For example, when URL is hit, it should show "we do not support internet explorer" html page rather than my main landing page.

is there any demo available for the same which I can inject into my app.???

TIA

Comment: It sounds more like a server-side concern...

Comment: You could use a conditional comment like in https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/41b9f1a36a746bccb996615cca2dc431bc637a77/index.html#L17 e.g. `<!--[if lt IE 8]> Stop using old IE! <![endif]-->`